# How to change a property when an attribute changes in the view(Source attribute in image tag) in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I have an image and I want to get notified when the source of my image changes by the user. So when the user changes the image it should automatically change in the view model.

This code is where my image source changes.

```
OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
{
        Image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(fileDialog.FileName)); //here I want to 
         //change the imagePath in my view model too.
        isImageChanged = true;
}
```

xaml code

```
<Image Width="50"
       Name = "Image"
       Height="50"
       Source="{Binding ImagePath,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged},Converter={StaticResource StringToPathConverter}">
            
</Image>
```

view model

```
private string _imagePath;
public string ImagePath
{
   get
   {
     return _imagePath;
   }
   set
   {
       _imagePath = value;
       OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ImagePath));//break point
   }
}
```

And here is the converter code

```
public class StringToPathConverter:IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string res = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString() + "images\\" + value;
            return res;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {            
            string res = Path.GetFileName(value.ToString());
            return res;
        }
    }
```

I set a breakpoint on set of imagePath and it didn't work. I don't know if it is possible to do it with binding and if it is or it's not how?

Comment: Please show the code of StringToPathConverter.

Comment: I added the converter. turned out my issue was just the Mode= TwoWay in my source attribute. Even though I had a convert back method it didn't work because it wasn't twoWay.

Comment: You can use `System.IO.Path.GetFileName` method instead to extract file name.

Comment: where can I use it? You mean in my first code block instead of  fileDialog.FileName?

Comment: At ConvertBack method of StringToPathConverter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Binding of the `Image.Source` property is `OneWay` by default.

You have to declare it as `TwoWay`:

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImagePath,
                Mode=TwoWay,
                Converter={StaticResource StringToPathConverter}}"/>
```

Be aware that this requires a working implementation of the `ConvertBack` method of your `StringToPathConverter`, which would have to convert from `ImageSource` to a path string.

You should avoid that and instead change the source property directly:

```
if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    viewModel.ImagePath = fileDialog.FileName;
}
```